# Can core data be used without tableView?

Tags: iphone

I've seen some sample code about core data. All of that uses navigation base template where the tableView is already provided. When I remove the tableView or use window base template, it kept crashing with the console stated the same error, something like it couldn't find this entity name. And the entity name is exactly the same (in @"" as it should be). So can I use core data to do saving without having those table?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Definitely ! Both aren't event related in fact. Core Data is for Data persistence while UITableView if for data presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Core Date is the model part in the "Model-View-Controller" pattern. This means Core Data is not depending on the view or (view)controllers.

You need to give a bit more info (just edit your question) before we can figure out what exactly goes wrong. Maybe you should start out with a Core Data tutorial to get a grip on the rules that apply.

This is a good read, pretty abstract and a good starting point for doing a core data tutorial later on or better understand the example code you are digging around in:)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CoreData.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna check it out